# How to keep custom Selection formatting on UITableView when scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, select, scroll

I've got a TableView with static cells that are selectable (one can be selected at a time), and I've set a custom "SelectionView" so that when a cell is selected, a blue outline appears around it.

The problem is when I either scroll OR leave the view and return (by going to another view controller), my custom formatting "breaks" in some way.  Sometimes it disappears (upon scrolling) and sometimes it seems to erase half of the outline (when i leave the view controller and return.)

Is there a way to ensure that my custom selection view stays there?

Here is my code:

```
class BackgroundDesignController: UITableViewController {

    let selectionView = UIView()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var  selectedBackground = "my default"

    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if(indexPath == [0,0]){
            BackgroundName = "blank"
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("BackgroundDesignNotification"), object: nil)
        }
        if(indexPath == [0,1]) {
            BackgroundName = "leaves"
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("BackgroundDesignNotification"), object: nil)
        }
        if(indexPath == [0,2]) {
            BackgroundName = "water"
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("BackgroundDesignNotification"), object: nil)
        }
        if(indexPath == [0,3]) {
            BackgroundName = "wood"
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("BackgroundDesignNotification"), object: nil)
        }          
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if cell.isSelected {
            cell.isSelected = true
        } else {
            cell.isSelected = false
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //customize the selectedBackgroundView
        selectionView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
        selectionView.layer.borderWidth = 6.0 //
        UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = selectionView
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)

        //reset the selected background  to the current value of the Background user default
        switch BackgroundName{
        case "blank":
            myTableView.selectRow(at: [0,0], animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        case "leaves":
            myTableView.selectRow(at: [0,1], animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        case "water":
            myTableView.selectRow(at: [0,2], animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        case "wood":
            myTableView.selectRow(at: [0,3], animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        default:
            print("There is a problem: no value for BackgroundName")
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your issue, you are not reseting properly the states of your cells.
Keep in mind that when you scroll, the tableview will reuse cells. So it means you'll need to reset their states usually in the `cellForRowAt` function.
But as you are using static cells, you might need to do that in the `willDisplayCell`.
If we have a look to your implementation of that function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            if cell.isSelected {
                cell.isSelected = true
            } else {
                cell.isSelected = false
            }
        }
```

This is a non sense. You assign `true` to `isSelected` if `isSelected` is `true`...
So you definitely have an issue here.

Also you are setting the selected states of your cells in the `viewWillAppear`, but what happens if the cell you are trying to select is not visible? I can tell you: nothing. So this code has to move somewhere else.

This is a very simple behaviour you are trying to do. I really recommend using dynamic cells, this is much easier to handle.

Comment: I appreciate that you pointed out where I have "nonsense" code... but can you help me identify how to fix it?

Comment: Sure, sorry my answer is a bit rash. I'll update my answer trying to be more precise.